# Is my usage of the term "context" and its related verbs in this context meaningful?

Tags: word-choice, collocation, programming

In speech and writing, the meaning of *[context](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/context)* is:

> 1.1 The parts of something written or spoken that **immediately** precede and follow a word or passage and clarify its meaning:

HTML or XML codes seem to use the broader sense of *[context](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/context)*:

Consider the hierarchical structure of a document in XML

```
<document>
<header> English language Usage </header>
<body>
   <question>
     Is it a good object?
   </question>
   <answer>
     No this is a good for export!
   </answer>
</body>
</document>
```

For example any container in a webpage could be counted as context for the sub-elements (e.g. header, body, question, answer,...), but those containers are not necessarily immediately *before* or *after*.

Imposing boundaries (e.g. starting and ending points) on this *context* within a webpage, we might apply the verbs *open* and *close* metaphorically in sentences like these:

> - *This element **opens** a context which expands to its related elements...*
> - *To **close** this context, we should specify an ending ....*

Are there any other useful verbs that could be used to talk about imposing these boundaries of context?

Comment: I doubt you can open or close context. It is called '*con*text' because it exists all around text or speech and is not something we can exactly measure.

Comment: @Sander, I myself defined the term, specially in Web pages, to denote different parts of a page (e.g. footer, header, content, sidebar,....) then I am not sure with this artificial concept, can I use those verbs?

Comment: To specify different parts of pages I would use a phrase similar to *to move on to the next **subject**...*

Comment: If you yourself are defining a non-standard usage, is it sensible to ask for collocates / idiomatic usages?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, but I would like to get sure its not too odd, and a future reader can imagine it in the context.

Comment: It is odd and confusing, IMO.

Comment: @ScotM Thank you for your edit, I edited it further. Please reconsider it if the modification are any helpful!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say "This word *marks the beginning* of the context" or "The context begins with this word."

"Closing a context" is getting into programming thought patterns rather than general perceptions of speech context.  A context has an ending, of course, but we don't normally think of it as "remaining open unless explicitly closed". In programming, you must identify the character positions in the text stream which mark the context boundaries, or identify the DOM elements that start and end the context.

Comment: Thank you, then you say it's sensible to call a portion of a Web page which begins with a DOM element and ends with another DOM element, or begins with a opening tag like `<div>` and end with a closing tag (`</div>`) a context?

Comment: Yes, in programming contexts, the document is a context; each container node in the document is a context;, and since the model is nested, you have nested contexts.

Comment: However maybe I can use `pattern` instead of context! Do you recommend that?

Comment: *Pattern* seems rather too general. *Context* suggests a boundedness in a way that pattern does not.